# Ruby Constant Lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is probably a simple question, but I'm trying to lookup the constant name in Ruby from the value. For example:

```
class Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base
  ACTIVE    = 1
  PENDING   = 2
  CANCELED  = 3
  SENT      = 4
  SUSPENDED = 5
end
```

I have a status of `1` in my db. I want to retrieve `ACTIVE` based on this so that I can display it in a view.

What's a good way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Module
  def constant_by_value( val )
    constants.find{ |name| const_get(name)==val }
  end
end

class Xyz
  ACTIVE    = 1
  PENDING   = 2
  CANCELED  = 3
  SENT      = 4
  SUSPENDED = 5
end

p Xyz.constant_by_value(4)
#=> :SENT
```

However, I wouldn't do this: using programmatic names as values for a *view* seems like a bad idea. You're likely to run into a situation where you want to change the display name (*maybe "suspended" should be shown as "on hold"*) and then you have to refactor your code.

I'd put a mapping in your view or controller, using the constants from the model:

```
status_name = {
  Xyz::ACTIVE    => "Active",
  Xyz::PENDING   => "Pending", 
  Xyz::CANCELED  => "Canceled", 
  Xyz::SENT      => "Away!", 
  Xyz::Suspended => "On Hold"
}
@status = status_name[@xyz.status_id]
```

Comment: I like this and agree that using programmatic names can be a bad idea for views (in fact, i just changed some code like that).  But do i really need to have the constant name in mapping you proposed? Won't @status = status_name[@xyz.status_id]
 just retrieve the status to be displayed in the view directly?

Comment: No, you don't _need_ to use the constant when declaring your mapping—e.g. `status_name = { 1=>"Active", … }`— but to not do so is to make your code fragile.

Answer (score 5):

I would put it into a constant array.

```
class xzy < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUSES = %w{ACTIVE PENDING CANCELLED SENT SUSPENDED}

  def get_status
    STATUSES[self.status-1]
  end

  def get_status_id(name)
    STATUSES.index(name) + 1
  end
end
```

The minus 1 in #get_status and + 1 in #get_status_id are for zero-indexed arrays. I added the second method as I have found myself needing that from time to time.

Comment: Would it make sense to move those methods to a view helper instead of having them in the model?

Comment: It would work, but generally you want to keep the model about the data. This way the model can tell the view what text to use. Helpers are generally used for building some HTML output, to keep the view code clean.

Comment: To clarify your last comment regarding using the model for the data. Since I'm trying to display in the view, shouldn't the view actually determine the final presentation of the data. Since in this case, these are really DB Statuses rather than the final output to be displayed? I sort of agree with Phrogz's comment below.  Thanks for the help, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

If your constants aren't always going to be drawn from small integers, you could also try:

```
class Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def int_to_status(x)
      constants.find{ |c| const_get(c) == x }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Love the simplicity and my constants are definitely not always small integers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
class Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base

  STATUSES = { 
    1 => ACTIVE,
    2 => PENDING,
    3 => CANCELED,
    4 => SENT,
    5 => SUSPENDED
  }

  def status_name
    STATUSES[ status ]   
  end

  def status_by_name( name )
    STATUSES.key( name ) 
  end

end
```

Comment: you need to define the constants ACTIVE, PENDING, etc. before you use them in the hash... but in general i think your solution is the most ruby-ish

Comment: That's for sure. But I've tried to mimic author's example, and don't wanna pollute my post with useless definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Phrogz I think this could be an option too:

```
module Xyz
  ACTIVE    = 1
  PENDING   = 2
  CANCELED  = 3
  SENT      = 4
  SUSPENDED = 5      

  def self.constant_by_value( val )
    constants.find{ |name| const_get(name)==val }
  end
end

Xyz.constant_by_value(2)
#=> :PENDING
```

I mention this because sometimes I find handy to keep my constants completely isolated from a particular class.